# Set AdditionalProperties of OpenAPI to false by default

Tags: openapi

My OpenAPI specification contains a lot of objects. According to the [spec](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#additionalProperties), a free-form object will by default have `additionProperties:true`. This is why when I use NSwag to generate a C# client, all requests and responses contain a dictionary `AdditionalProperties`. I don't need these additional properties.

Is there a way of changing the default value for `additionalProperties` such that I don't have to modify every object in my API?